# Outlook/Word email signature names limited to 32 characters when added via code

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, office365, office-interop

Our organization uses a script to configure email signatures for users.  We recently upgraded to Office 365 and the script stopped working as expected.  It turns out, that Microsoft has apparently made some change that requires the signature name to end with a space, followed by the email address in parentheses.  For example, instead of naming the signature **HTML Signature**, it must now be named **HTML Signature (user@org.com)**.

The Outlook user interface hides the "space + email address" portion of the signature name when you view the signature editor.  But that suffix must be part of the name now in order to be associated with the email account.  This is a breaking change and it has a limitation that causes a problem.

In Outlook, you can create a signature with a long name and it will be properly associated with the account - as long as you create it from the UI.  But... if you create it via code, using `EmailOptions.EmailSignature.EmailSignatureEntries.Add`, it cannot exceed 32 characters in length.  This is a problem because many of our users have email addresses that cause the total length of the signature name to exceed 32 characters.

I would expect the interop API to not enforce character length limitations that the UI does not.  More ideally, the signature names should NOT have to include the email address.  Alternatively, there should be another mechanism for associating signatures to accounts.

We require a way to overcome this limitation via code.

Comment: This isn't a "code writing on demand" site. If your script uses InterOp, then the VBA tag is irrelevant. Please post your script with your attempts to fix the problem, then we may be able to help you to debug it.

Comment: At no point in my question did I request assistance with writing code, and I don't appreciate the unnecessarily hostile "code writing on demand" comment. I didn't post my code, because I'm not looking for assistance writing code. I'm simply following Microsoft's documented recommendation for posting VBA programming questions. I happen to agree with you that this isn't a VBA issue, but that's where and how they have this functionality documented and the documentation instructs developers to post questions here and tag them with VBA. It's a poor, out-dated categorization.

Comment: Interop is not VBA. If you are using interop, the VBA tag is wrong and misleading. Microsoft is giving you bad information, please post the Microsoft URL where you read this. What is "We require a way to overcome this limitation via code.", if not a request for code? Here are the Stack Overflow guidelines for on-topic questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic